# can i access python script from ionic application

Tags: python, ionic-framework, machine-learning

I am building an **offline** ionic application and need to be integrate it with my python script contains a standalone ML model trained and exported from the microsoft custom vision which classifies the trees.it takes **picture as an input** and **returns a string**.

> python server.py image.png

this returns an output as

> Mango tree

How can we access the python script or how to make it as a service ?

Answer (score 1):

1) Create API to accept image and give tree name

- https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/build-simple-restful-api-with-python-and-flask-part-1-fae9ff66a706
- https://www.codementor.io/sagaragarwal94/building-a-basic-restful-api-in-python-58k02xsiq

2) Create service in Ionic app to upload image and return response

- can use file input in page to select image from files for browser app
- can use https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin for iPhone app

  - can use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/ for android

Comment: Where as i'm developing the application as completely offline so i can't make it with the api's and also i didn't get the use of file-chooser for android could you please tell me about that